# Row Level Security In QlikView

Tags: security, qlikview

I have created `Section Access` and assigned three users:

```
ADMIN -> ADMIN
USER  -> USER1
USER  -> USER2
```

Say there are three Segments - A,B AND C

`USER1` should see only access segment `B`

`USER2` should see only access segment `C`

`ADMIN` should see all segments

I've logged in as `USER1` and can see only `Segment B`. But after script reload i'm able to see all three segments even though i'm logged in as `USER1`

Also when i'm logged in as `ADMIN` i can see only `Segment B` and `Segment C` but not `Segment A`

Comment: Possible to share the section access script?

Comment: I have found the answer. Whatever Segments have been mentioned for the users.. Those only will also be shown for admin.. Incase we need all segments then we need to create seperate users consisting of other Segments